# How can I save two results of the same id using vue-multiselect in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pivot-table, crud, multi-select

I'm creating a Vue Laravel SPA and I have an `employees` and `positions` table. Then I'm trying to create a pivot table with many to many relationships between these tables. How can I save a record with the same `employees_id` if for example I have selected 2 selections in `vue-multiselect` to a pivot table?

Here's my employees table:

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateEmployeesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id()->unique();
            $table->string('first_name', 50);
            $table->string('middle_name', 50);
            $table->string('last_name', 50);
            $table->unsignedInteger('designation_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('position_id');
            $table->string('address');
            $table->dateTime('birthdate');
            $table->dateTime('date_hired');
            $table->decimal('basic_pay');
            $table->string('cost_classification');
            $table->string('sss_number', 25);
            $table->string('philhealth_number', 25);
            $table->string('pagibig_number', 25);
            $table->string('emergency_contact_name');
            $table->string('contact_number')->unique()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->timestamp('deleted_at')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('employees');
    }
}
```

My employees model:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

use App\Models\Positions;

class Employees extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'employees';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $timestamps = true;
    
    protected $casts = ['basic_pay' => 'decimal:2'];

    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at', 'date_hired'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'designation_id',
        'position_id',
        'basic_pay',
        'date_hired',
        'cost_classification',
        'sss_number',
        'philhealth_number',
        'pagibig_number',
        'emergency_contact_name',
        'contact_number'
    ];

    public function positions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Positions::class);
    }
}
```

My positions table:

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePositionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('positions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->longText('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->timestamp('deleted_at')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('positions');
    }
}
```

Positions model:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

use App\Models\Employees;

class Positions extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'positions';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $timestamps = true;
    
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description'
    ];

    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Employees::class, 'employees_positions', 'employees_id', 'positions_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

My pivot `employees_positions` table:

Then my `create-employee.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <main>
        <h3 class="text-2xl text-gray-800 font-bold leading-none mb-6">Create Employee</h3>
        <div class="px-5 py-6 shadow-sm rounded-md bg-white">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <form @submit.prevent="addEmployee">
                        <div class="flex space-x-6 md:w-3/4">
                            <div class="md:w-3/6 mb-4 flex-1">
                                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 required" for="name">First Name</label>
                                <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" tabindex="1" v-model="form.first_name" :class="form.errors.has('first_name')?'border-2 border-red-600':'border'" />
                                <p class="text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 text-sm" v-if="form.errors.has('first_name')" v-html="form.errors.get('first_name')" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="md:w-3/6 mb-4 flex-1">
                                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 required" for="name">Last Name</label>
                                <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" tabindex="2" v-model="form.last_name" :class="form.errors.has('last_name')?'border-2 border-red-600':'border'" />
                                <p class="text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 text-sm" v-if="form.errors.has('last_name')" v-html="form.errors.get('last_name')" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex space-x-6 md:w-3/4">
                            <div class="md:w-3/6 mb-4 flex-1">
                                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 required" for="designation_id">Designation</label>
                                <div :class="form.errors.has('designation_id')?'border-2 border-red-600':''">
                                    <multiselect
                                        v-model="form.designation_id"
                                        :options="designation_options.map(designation => designation.id)" 
                                        :custom-label="opt => designation_options.find(designation => designation.id == opt).name"
                                        :multiple="true"
                                        :taggable="true"
                                        :tabindex="3"
                                    ></multiselect>
                                </div>
                                <p class="text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 text-sm" v-if="form.errors.has('designation_id')" v-html="form.errors.get('designation_id')" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="md:w-3/6 mb-4 flex-1">
                                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 required" for="position_id">Position</label>
                                <div :class="form.errors.has('position_id')?'border-2 border-red-600':''">
                                    <multiselect
                                        v-model="form.position_id"
                                        :options="position_options.map(position => position.id)" 
                                        :custom-label="opt => position_options.find(position => position.id == opt).name"
                                        :multiple="true"
                                        :taggable="true"
                                        :tabindex="4"
                                    ></multiselect>
                                </div>
                                <p class="text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 text-sm" v-if="form.errors.has('position_id')" v-html="form.errors.get('position_id')" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex space-x-6 md:w-3/4">
                            <div class="mb-4" style="width: 620px;">
                                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 required" for="address">Address</label>
                                <textarea class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" rows="1" placeholder="" tabindex="5"></textarea>
                                <p class="text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 text-sm" v-if="form.errors.has('address')" v-html="form.errors.get('address')" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="md:w-1/3 mb-4">
                                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 required" for="birthdate">Birthdate</label>
                                <input type="date" name="birthdate" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" tabindex="6" v-model="form.birthdate" :class="form.errors.has('birthdate')?'border-2 border-red-600':'border'" />
                                <p class="text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 text-sm" v-if="form.errors.has('birthdate')" v-html="form.errors.get('birthdate')" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="md:w-1/3 mb-4">
                                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 required" for="date_hired">Date Hired</label>
                                <input type="date" name="date_hired" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" tabindex="7" v-model="form.date_hired" :class="form.errors.has('date_hired')?'border-2 border-red-600':'border'" />
                                <p class="text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 text-sm" v-if="form.errors.has('date_hired')" v-html="form.errors.get('date_hired')" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex space-x-6 md:w-3/4">
                            <div class="md:w-1/3 mb-4">
                                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 required" for="sss_number">SSS Number</label>
                                <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" name="sss_number" id="sss_number" type="text" placeholder="SSS Number" tabindex="8" v-model="form.sss_number" :class="form.errors.has('sss_number')?'border-2 border-red-600':'border'" />
                                <p class="text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 text-sm" v-if="form.errors.has('sss_number')" v-html="form.errors.get('sss_number')" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="md:w-1/3 mb-4">
                                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 required" for="philhealth_number">Philhealth Number</label>
                                <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" name="philhealth_number" id="philhealth_number" type="text" placeholder="Philhealth Number" tabindex="9" v-model="form.last_name" :class="form.errors.has('philhealth_number')?'border-2 border-red-600':'border'" />
                                <p class="text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 text-sm" v-if="form.errors.has('philhealth_number')" v-html="form.errors.get('philhealth_number')" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="md:w-1/3 mb-4">
                                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 required" for="pagibig_number">Pagibig Number</label>
                                <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" name="pagibig_number" id="pagibig_number" type="text" placeholder="Pagibig Number" tabindex="10" v-model="form.pagibig_number" :class="form.errors.has('pagibig_number')?'border-2 border-red-600':'border'" />
                                <p class="text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 text-sm" v-if="form.errors.has('pagibig_number')" v-html="form.errors.get('pagibig_number')" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex space-x-6 md:w-3/4">
                            <div class="md:w-3/6 mb-4 flex-1">
                                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 required" for="basic_pay">Basic Pay</label>
                                <div class="relative rounded">
                                    <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 pl-3 flex items-center pointer-events-none">
                                        <span class="text-gray-700">₱</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 pl-8 pr-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" name="basic_pay" id="basic_pay" type="number" step="any"  placeholder="00.00" tabindex="11" v-model="form.basic_pay" :class="form.errors.has('basic_pay')?'border-2 border-red-600':'border'" />
                                    <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center"><label for="basic_pay" class="sr-only">Basic Pay</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <p class="text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 text-sm" v-if="form.errors.has('basic_pay')" v-html="form.errors.get('basic_pay')" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="md:w-3/6 mb-4 flex-1">
                                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 required" for="cost_classification">Cost Classification</label>
                                <div :class="form.errors.has('cost_classification')?'border-2 border-red-600':''">
                                    <multiselect
                                        v-model="form.cost_classification"
                                        :options="cost_classification_options"
                                        :multiple="false"
                                        :taggable="false"
                                        :tabindex="12"
                                    ></multiselect>
                                </div>
                                <p class="text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 text-sm" v-if="form.errors.has('cost_classification')" v-html="form.errors.get('cost_classification')" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="flex space-x-6 md:w-3/4">
                            <div class="md:w-3/6 mb-4 flex-1">
                                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 required" for="emergency_contact">Emergency Contact</label>
                                <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" name="emergency_contact" id="emergency_contact" type="text" placeholder="Emergency Contact" tabindex="13" v-model="form.emergency_contact" :class="form.errors.has('emergency_contact')?'border-2 border-red-600':'border'" />
                                <p class="text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 text-sm" v-if="form.errors.has('emergency_contact')" v-html="form.errors.get('emergency_contact')" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="md:w-3/6 mb-4 flex-1">
                                <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2 required" for="contact_number">Contact Number</label>
                                <input class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" name="contact_number" id="contact_number" type="text" placeholder="Contact Number" tabindex="14" v-model="form.contact_number" :class="form.errors.has('contact_number')?'border-2 border-red-600':'border'" />
                                <p class="text-red-600 dark:text-red-500 text-sm" v-if="form.errors.has('contact_number')" v-html="form.errors.get('contact_number')" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="sm:hidden md:flex bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-400 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 border-b-4 border-blue-700 hover:border-blue-500 rounded outline-none focus:outline-none">Create</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</template>
<style src="vue-multiselect/dist/vue-multiselect.min.css"></style>
<script>
    import Form from 'vform'
    import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect'

    export default {
        components: { Multiselect },
        data: () => ({
            errors: {},
            form: new Form({
                designation_id: [],
                position_id: [],
                cost_classification: []
            }),
            designation_options: [],
            position_options: [],
            cost_classification_options: ['Direct Labor', 'Indirect Labor', 'General & Admin']
        }),
        methods: {
            addEmployee() {
                this.form
                    .post('/api/employees', this.form)
                    .then(res => {
                        this.$swal({
                                title: 'Are you sure?',
                                text: 'Do you want to save this record?',
                                icon: 'warning',
                                showCancelButton: true,
                                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, save it!'
                            }).then((result) => {
                                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                                    this.$router.push({ name: 'employees' })
                                    this.$swal(
                                        'Good job!',
                                        'You save the record!',
                                        'success'
                                    )
                                }
                            });
                        })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
            },
            getDesignationNames() {
                this.axios.get('/api/designations').then((res) => {
                    this.designation_options = res.data;
                }).catch(err => console.log(err));
            },
            getPositionNames() {
                this.axios.get('/api/positions').then((res) => {
                    this.position_options = res.data;
                }).catch(err => console.log(err));
            },
        },
        created: function() {
            this.getDesignationNames();
            this.getPositionNames();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just find position model and use attach() or sync() as bellow:

```
$position->employees()->sync([array_of_employees]);
```

Comment: should it be `$employee->positions()->sync($request->input('position_id'));` instead and added on EmployeesController.php?